# How can I store the background?

Tags: android, canvas

I have a linechart, what I would like to achieve not to redraw the grid each time. I tried the following, but the grid only visible in the first time, it seams that the saveLayer not working, or I just making it in the wrong way.

```
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        if (mRedrawGrid) {
            drawGrid(canvas);
            mGridLayer = canvas.saveLayer(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), mPaint, Canvas.MATRIX_SAVE_FLAG);
        } else
            canvas.restoreToCount(mGridLayer);
        drawLineChart(canvas);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May this help you:

Buddy take your `Canvas` on a `LinearLayout` and then save the whole `LinearLayout's` background into a bitmap like:

```
ll.buildDrawingCache();
Bitmap bt = ll.getDrawingCache();
```